# How can I filter specific paths with a filter and authenticate with LDAP on /login only?

Tags: java, spring, security, ldap, jwt

I'm trying to authenticate with Basic Auth though LDAP but I only need to do so with /login route. All the other routes need to be authenticated through a custom JWT Filter that I implemented. Actually, what I've done just doesn't work.

Edit : just to be more clear, at the moment when I call on /auth/login, it goes through the LDAP filter and not the JWT Filter. But when I call any other route, it goes through JWT Filter and then still goes through the LDAP one and always makes my request fail. The behaviour is only correct when it's the /auth/login call.

Here's the configuration :

```
public class SecurityConfiguration {

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 21)
public static class CompanySecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private LdapContextSource ldapContextSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication().contextSource(ldapContextSource).userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .httpBasic().and()
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/auth/login")
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 20)
public static class JWTSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/projects", "/projects/**", "/credential/**")
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(new JWTFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().cors().disable();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: 'just doesn't work' means what exactly?

Comment: It still goes though the first filter (the LDAP one), even after I go through the JWTFilter. I just want to exclude the LDAP Filter on all routes except /auth/login and never go through the JWTFilter when I call /auth/login. They are mutually exclusive. The LDAP filter handles a basic auth header and the other one, a Bearer token. (Note : I have edited my question based on yours)